# Android multiple numberpickers in same activity

Tags: android

I need to put three numberpickers in one activity.

My problem is that all of them "become active" when I click the screen.

I want each of them "become active" when clicking the corresponding button.
I think that the problem is in "onClick" function but I don't know how to solve it.

```
public class personal_data extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView e_number;
Button e_numberpicker;

TextView a_number;
Button a_numberpicker;

TextView p_number;
Button p_numberpicker;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_personal_data);

    e_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_e);
    e_numberpicker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_e);
    e_numberpicker.setOnClickListener(this);

    a_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_a);
    a_numberpicker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_a);
    a_numberpicker.setOnClickListener(this);

    p_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_p);
    p_numberpicker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_p);
    p_numberpicker.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public  void onClick(View v){
    e_setNumberpicker();
    a_setNumberpicker();
    p_setNumberpicker();
}

private void e_setNumberpicker() {
    NumberPicker e_myNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
    e_myNumberPicker.setMaxValue(110);
    e_myNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            e_number.setText(""+newVal);
        }
    };
    e_myNumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);
    AlertDialog.Builder e_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(e_myNumberPicker);
    e_builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

        }
    });
    e_builder.show();
}

private void a_setNumberpicker() {
    NumberPicker a_myNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
    a_myNumberPicker.setMaxValue(210);
    a_myNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            a_number.setText(""+newVal);
        }
    };
    a_myNumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);
    AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(a_myNumberPicker);
    a_builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

        }
    });
    a_builder.show();
}

private void p_setNumberpicker() {
    NumberPicker p_myNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
    p_myNumberPicker.setMaxValue(150);
    p_myNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            p_number.setText(""+newVal);
        }
    };
    p_myNumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);
    AlertDialog.Builder p_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(p_myNumberPicker);
    p_builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

        }
    });
    p_builder.show();
}
}
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check which view triggered the `onClick`

```
@Override
public  void onClick(View v){
    if (v == e_numberpicker) {
        e_setNumberpicker();
    }
    if (v == a_numberpicker) {
        a_setNumberpicker();
    }
    if (v == [_numberpicker) {
        p_setNumberpicker();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also attach an **onClick listener** to individual `TextView` like this

```
 TextView e_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_e);

 e_number.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something 
            }

 });
```